# Why is the Java library source code so strangely indented?

Tags: indentation, java

I often rely on the JDK source code to understand how I should implement an interface, and I often find some very strange indentation style at use. For instance, in `DefaultCellEditor.java`:

```
public DefaultCellEditor(final JTextField textField) {
    editorComponent = textField;
this.clickCountToStart = 2;
    delegate = new EditorDelegate() {
        public void setValue(Object value) {
    textField.setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
        }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    return textField.getText();
    }
    };
textField.addActionListener(delegate);
}
```

I'm wondering if this is due to my IDE or not, since I find this kind of indentation quite strange and difficult to read.

Comment: Is this source code or decompiling from the IDE?

Comment: @david Netbeans 6.9.1, and same result with 7.0.1. I may investigate if the core packages also look the same or not.

Comment: @Petar Its source code, but accessed through the built-in archives of Netbeans. I'll try to access the real source code from the oracle website to compare.

Comment: On [Grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.java#DefaultCellEditor.%3Cinit%3E%28javax.swing.JTextField%29) and the [JDK6 source repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/0c738a3e5791/src/share/classes/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.java), the formatting looks fine -- although the former might reformat for display, the later most likely doesn't.

Comment: I'm not having this problem, using NetBeans.

Comment: I always wondered this myself. I just assumed I was the only one who ever noticed this. :)

Comment: I may have found the solution: actually, some lines seem to be indented with tabs and some others with spaces. I specified that tabs should be 4 spaces wide, but if I use 8 spaces for tabs, then the indentation is correct. So the issue seems to be caused by an indentation inconsistency: tabs and spaces are mixed together.

Comment: That's what I thought (see my answer) but also I linked you to the online source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the indentation is consistent across different methods, then there's probably some (unwritten) reason why it's that way.

If there's no rhyme or reason, then (a) the coder(s) didn't care about indentation, or (b) the coder(s) did care, and something happened en route to your computer.  The likely culprit is that not enough attention was given to how tabs and spaces were used to structure the code, and your IDE's indentation settings for tabs are different than those of the last person's who touched the code.

If you can make the whitespace characters visible in your text editor, that should show you if a mix of tabs and spaces was used.

Comment: Too bad I can't accept everyone answers. The error indeed came from an inconsistency in the source code: some lines are indented with tabs, some others with spaces. Forcing the tabs to be rendered with 8 spaces solved the issue, but this leads to another question: why are they mixing tabs and spaces? Different committers with different coding styles maybe...They should pay attention to that.

Comment: Right.  Converting tabs to spaces can be done within the IDE.  In mine, each time I push the TAB key, four spaces are inserted.  Tabs never enter my code.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a [tab vs spaces](http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html) issue.  Try setting the tab width to 4 spaces (or 8 if it is 4).

Here is what I see when browsing the [OpenJDK code for DefaultCellEditor](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6-gate/jdk/file/b139627f7bc3/src/share/classes/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.java) online.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your IDE is ignoring or otherwise misinterpreting tab characters.

Comment: Then the question shifts to "why are they mixing tabs and spaces".

Comment: As I commented on the question, delnan, it is indeed the case: tabs seem to be mixed with spaces, for the happiness of everyone :)

Comment: Nope, the IDE is correct. The indentation is really like that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that NetBeans formats the code of the Java Source Code (`src.jar`). I extracted the jar manually and I opened `javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.java` using a plain text editor and the indentation is really that bad. So, it is **not** the IDE.

But why the indentation is that bad;  sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, the good old text editor may be using 4 spaces for tabs, and not 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is IDE/editor problem on author's side.

Back in my PHP days I used PSPad editor which does something very similar to this - in PSPad indentation looks OK but in other viewers/editors indentation is mangled. AFAIK it has something to do with mixing spaces with tabulators and different tab width.